# SORM and trait as field type

Tags: mysql, scala, sorm

I'm using latest **SORM** v0.3.15 with MySQL.

Is it possible to use a trait as field's type of an entity? Since I'd like to implement following thing:

```
trait Votable

case class Post(...) extends Votable
case class Comment(...) extends Votable

case class VoteHistory(.., source: Votable)
```

And I have some doubts about it due to how sorm works (reflection and etc)

For now I have an exception `Caused by: sorm.core.SormException: Unsupported type: models.entities.Votable`

Answer (score 1):

According to the source code your `Votable` type should be one of: Range, Seq, Set, Map, Option, AnyVal, String, BigDecimal, *Date, Time*, Enumeration, Tuple1-22, or a case class.
Take a look at `./src/main/scala/sorm/mappings/MappingKind.scala` for details. Here is a snippet:

```
sealed trait MappingKind

object MappingKind {

  case object Enum             extends MappingKind
  case object Entity           extends MappingKind
  case object Value            extends MappingKind
  case object Tuple            extends MappingKind
  case object OptionToTable    extends MappingKind
  case object OptionToNullable extends MappingKind
  case object Seq              extends MappingKind
  case object Set              extends MappingKind
  case object Map              extends MappingKind
  case object Range            extends MappingKind

  def apply
    ( reflection : Reflection )
    : MappingKind
    = reflection match {
        case _
          if reflection <:< Reflection[scala.Range]
          => Range
        case _
          if reflection <:< Reflection[collection.Seq[_]]
          => Seq

        ...

        case _
          if (reflection <:< Reflection[Tuple1[_]])
          || (reflection <:< Reflection[Tuple2[_, _]])
          || (reflection <:< Reflection[Tuple3[_, _, _]])

        ...

          || (reflection <:< Reflection[Tuple22[_, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _]])
          => Tuple
        case _
          if reflection.isCaseClass
          => Entity
        case _
          => throw new SormException("Unsupported type: " + reflection)
      }
}
```

Supported data types [doc](http://sorm-framework.org/Documentation.html#data_types).

The reflection test used there is `./src/main/scala/sorm/reflection/Reflection.scala`:

```
  def isCaseClass
    = s match {
        case s : ClassSymbol => s.isCaseClass
        case _ => false
      }
```

The problem with `Votable` is that it's not a subtype of any of these listed types. Thus Scala can't ensure that subclasses of `Votable` will be compliant subtypes of a `MappingKind`. In other words there is no guarantee that you won't do this: `class A extends Votable` which is not serializable by Sorm, and then it would blow up at run time.

The problem is clear now, so we would want to for example make `Votable` a case class and inherit in another case class from it, but that's not allowed in Scala due to equality violations. Also there is no unified type in Scala that marks something to be a case class.

For example trying to fake a "case class type" fails:

```
scala> trait Votable
defined trait Votable

scala> case class Comment(b: String) extends Votable
defined class Comment

scala> def isCaseClassOrWhat_?(v: AnyRef): Boolean = {
     |   import reflect.runtime.universe._
     |   val typeMirror = runtimeMirror(v.getClass.getClassLoader)
     |   val instanceMirror = typeMirror.reflect(v)
     |   val symbol = instanceMirror.symbol
     |   symbol.isCaseClass
     | }
isCaseClassOrWhat_$qmark: (v: AnyRef)Boolean

scala> isCaseClassOrWhat_?(new Votable {});
res0: Boolean = false

scala> isCaseClassOrWhat_?(Comment("df"));
res1: Boolean = true

scala> trait VotableCaseClass extends Product with Serializable
defined trait VotableCaseClass

scala> isCaseClassOrWhat_?(new VotableCaseClass { def canEqual(that: Any): Boolean = ???; def productArity: Int = ???; def productElement(n: Int): Any = ??? });
res2: Boolean = false
```

From Scala compiler code if I read it right I could only understand that `isCaseClass` is implemented by compiler setting `CASE` flag on the class and `isCaseClass` testing for existence of this flag.

I don't know how to fix this particular problem. Maybe Storm could have another case/marker interface for this. It could be structural type check or `Product with Serializable` or something along those lines. Maybe it's possible to do this with Scala macros - I don't know much about them yet.

EDIT:

You could maybe use a `Map` type for serialization and convert case classes to `Map` like this:

```
def caseClassToMap(cc: Product): Map[String,Any] = {
  val fields = cc.getClass.getDeclaredFields.map(_.getName)
  fields.zip(cc.productIterator.to).toMap
}

scala> case class A(a: Int)
defined class A

scala> caseClass2Map(A(123))
res14: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any] = Map(a -> 123)
```

I didn't test if it works well with SORM.

Comment: Indeed, SORM does operate only on final types, because it extracts all the mapping information from them. "open" types like traits don't provide sufficient information. In OP's case I'd recommend to consider standard Scala enumerations, which are supported by SORM.

Comment: Thank you @NikitaVolkov for confirming that

Comment: Well, looks like the only way to achieve a goal (or similar one) is an implicit conversion from `Post` and `Comment` to case class `Votable`